How to align in wpf c# the radio button control the button of the control is a bit high then the text. how to align them in same height?
<GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header="Folder Selection" Margin="0,0,0,10">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <RadioButton Content="Save in Same Folder" IsChecked="{Binding IsSaveInSameFolder}" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <RadioButton Content="Save in Custom Folder" IsChecked="{Binding IsSaveInCustomFolder}" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
            <TextBox Width="300" Text="{Binding SelectedFolderPath}" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSaveInCustomFolder}" />
            <Button Content="Browse" Width="80" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Command="{Binding BrowseFolderCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSaveInCustomFolder}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</GroupBox>

the result in the designer:
in the screenshot image i marked the second one with red circles to explain better what i mean that the buttons or the selections of the radio buttons that are not aligned with the radio buttons texts.  

You can use VerticalContentAlignment="Center" so your code will be
<GroupBox Grid.Row="1" Header="Folder Selection" Margin="0,0,0,10">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <RadioButton Content="Save in Same Folder" IsChecked="{Binding IsSaveInSameFolder}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <RadioButton Content="Save in Custom Folder" IsChecked="{Binding IsSaveInCustomFolder}" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="20,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10">
                <TextBox Width="300" Text="{Binding SelectedFolderPath}" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSaveInCustomFolder}" />
                <Button Content="Browse" Width="80" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,0,0,0" Command="{Binding BrowseFolderCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding IsSaveInCustomFolder}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>

